# Two variants of same code in git: Branch, fork, or make separate repository?

Tags: git, version-control, github, merge, branch

I have the following two variants of a (96 file) code, and the ONLY differences between them are in brackets:

1. DOUBLE-PRECIION ( every variable is defined as REAL*8 and every number is defined like 1234D+02 )
2. QUADRUPLE-PRECISION ( every variable is defined as REAL*16 and every number is defined like 1234Q+02 )

**If I every change anything in the software, I want this change to be consistent in both of the above variants of the code.**

In Git(Hub), should I:

1. Build a separate repository (how am I going to easily merge changes ?),
2. Build a different branch (but branching seems to be best for when **all** code is to merge),
3. Build a fork (but this seems to be for people that can't push to the main branch) ?

Here are some questions that are related, but not what I want. I've written why I haven't swallowed their answers:

1. [maintain different versions of the code simultaneously using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315139/maintain-different-versions-of-the-code-simultaneously-using-git): Tobu's answer says "**git cherry-pick** may not work in many cases"
2. [managing multiple versions of a web application using git](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134357/managing-multiple-versions-of-a-web-application-using-git): suggests **git submodules** but there's [reasons not to](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/).
3. [Keeping track of source code variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454179/keeping-track-of-source-code-variants): suggests using **#define** , but is there a FORTRAN equivalent ?
4. [How to track two version of a project in one GIT repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024812/how-to-track-two-version-of-a-project-in-one-git-repository): suggests a 3rd branch for "common" code, but I don't see the benefit of having more than 2. And would I not need to use git cherry-pick here ?

Comment: I assume this code that needs near-duplication is in more than a couple of files, correct? Also, Fortran preprocessor commands: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-F6619F6F-7D70-4B06-A266-6F39EF6D51B7.htm

Comment: I think a preprocessor command is probably what you want (listed as your #3).

Comment: Thanks @BlackVegetable ! I considered this option but seeing just a handful of upvotes for the question AND answer, over more than a year meant it didn't strike me as an obvious best solution. I can see myself using #define to change REAL*8 to REAL*16 , but not so much to convert every instance of "4d3" into "4q3" and "2D+01" to "2Q+01" , do you know if I can just list these full numbers (without scientific notation at all) and rely on the compiler to convert them to whatever type of number their respective variables were defined as ?

Comment: Hmm, I honestly don't know much about Fortran.  While it wouldn't be optimal, you *could* write a script in whatever language you like to run a regex find/replace over those patterns that is executed at build-time.  It is not that uncommon to have to run a certain kind of "make" command after checking out a branch in git.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since I did any Fortran **but** if you can have parametrised macros based like you can in C you best bet would be to have a conditional macro something like

```
#define DECLARE_HIGH_PRECISION(Name, Val, Exp) \
#ifdef QUAD_PREC \
REAL*8 %Name% = %Val%Q%Exp% \
#else \
REAL*4 %Name% = %Val%D%Exp% \
#endif
```

The declare and initialise your values as `DECLARE_HIGH_PRECISION(Fred, 23, -3)` you will probably also need a macro for inline values that don't need a name so as to be able to do things like `Fred = Fred * HIGH_PRECISION(43, +6)`, etc.